# How to stream data to azure block blob in python

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage

I want to stream data to azure block blob with python. The code below creates the blob but ends up with zero bytes. How can I make this work?

```
import io
import struct
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

storage = BlockBlobService('acct-xxx', 'key-xxx')
stream = io.BytesIO()
storage.create_blob_from_stream("mycontainer", "myblob", stream)
stream.write(struct.pack("d", 12.34))
stream.write(struct.pack("d", 56.78))
stream.close()
```

Comment: Hi,Greg. Any progress?

Comment: I don't think the python library will serve my needs.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you've missed the key line of code：

> stream.seek(0)

I set the stream's `Position property` to 0 then your code works.

```
import io
import struct
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

storage = BlockBlobService('acct-xxx', 'key-xxx')
stream = io.BytesIO()

stream.write(struct.pack("d", 12.34))
stream.write(struct.pack("d", 56.78))
stream.seek(0)
storage.create_blob_from_stream("mycontainer", "myblob", stream)
stream.close()
```

[image]

You could refer to this thread [Azure storage: Uploaded files with size zero bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905754/azure-storage-uploaded-files-with-size-zero-bytes).

Comment: This would require holding the entire stream in memory. I want to stream  data as I get it without incurring a large memory footprint.

Comment: @GregClinton Hi,Greg. storage.create_blob_from_stream is a http request package for rest API actually, it's a synchronous blocking mode so you can't operate stream that has been uploaded to azure.

Comment: This one is a life saver. I had seeked to the end to find the size of a flask file and forgot to seek back! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using smart_open.

```py
from smart_open import open

# stream from Azure Blob Storage
with open('azure://my_container/my_file.txt') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        print(line)

# stream content *into* Azure Blob Storage (write mode):
with open('azure://my_container/my_file.txt', 'wb') as fout:
    fout.write(b'hello world')
```